# sys/cdefs.h:no such file or directory on arm v7 architecture with ubuntu trusty

Tags: libraries

With amd64 i found in the blogs related to this that try installing lib6-dev-i386 to solve this  but i really do not have any idea which package to install for arm v7 cpu on imx6 board so that this error doesn't come up.
Moreover, this file was present in /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cdefs.h when i searched for it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First check the architecture:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
armhf
```

Install  `linux-libc-dev-armhf` , `libc6-armhf` and `libc6-dev-armhf`. All these packages are for ubuntu 14.04 (trusty tahr) from [ubuntu.packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/libc6-dev-armhf-cross)

and finally it works.LOL